# How to use a mutex in FreeRTOS?

Tags: mutex, semaphore, freertos

I have a shared resources, which shared by an ISR and a normal task. It need to be serialized accessed. It seems that neither the BinarySemaphore nor the MutexSemaphore meets my needs. Which utility is supposed to be used?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally not a good idea to use a mutex in an interrupt.  For a start, if the interrupt is running, then it can't be interrupted by a task, so only one way protection is really needed.  Second, if the interrupt can't obtain the mutex, then it can't block to wait for it, so it would have to exit without accessing the resource.

If the interrupt needs to do something long winded consider deferring the interrupt processing to a task, either to one of your own tasks using a [direct to task notification](http://www.freertos.org/RTOS-task-notifications.html), or using the [centralised deferred interrupt processing](http://www.freertos.org/xTimerPendFunctionCallFromISR.html) feature.

If just must use a semaphore in an interrupt, use a binary semaphore, not a mutex, as mutexes have a priority inheritance mechanism that makes little logical sense in an interrupt (priority inheritance is about tasks inheriting each other's task priority, but an interrupt is not a task, and so does not have a task priority).

Comment: I do not think the BinarySemaphore meets the requirement.

Comment: Since BinarySemaphore is used as one "only" take while another only "give". But "exclusive access to shared resources" want both of them can take and giveback the resources.

Comment: Does that mean i have to use two BinarySemaphore to simulate the "Exclusive Accesss". ISR take BinarySemA, then use the resources, then ISR give BinarySemB. Task take BinarySemB, then use the resources, then Give the BinarySemA.